# how to send multiple strings to another page using # anchor

Tags: html, forms, anchor, href

I need to pass multiple strings to the div id='scarica' on another page scaricaMagazzino.php I'm using # anchor but do not work. There is something wrong with string concatenation & or with ?string=... I don't know how to associate strings to the div id name, probably ? is wrong

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'>                                  
    <a href="crudMagazzino.php#scarica?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&amp;
                                          codice=<?php echo $codice; ?>&amp;
                                          cod_forn=<?php echo $cod_forn; ?>&amp;
                                          ubicazione=<?php echo $ubicazione; ?>&amp;
                                          descrizione=<?php echo $descrizione; ?>&amp;
                                          package=<?php echo $package; ?>&amp;
                                          quantita=<?php echo $quantita; ?>&amp;">                                  
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' href="#scarica=<?php echo $id;?>" data-toggle="modal"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus' aria-hidden='true' title="Scarica"></span></button>
    </a>
</form>
```

Inside the form there are other 3 buttons: this is for unload then there are load, edit & delete

crudMagazzino.php

```
<?php //include 'menu.html'; 
$id = $_GET['id'];
$codice = $_GET['codice'];
$cod_forn = $_GET['cod_forn'];
$ubicazione = $_GET['ubicazione'];
$descrizione = $_GET['descrizione'];
$package = $_GET['package'];
$quantita = $_GET['quantita'];
?>

<!--Unload q.ty Modal -->
<div id="scarica<?php echo $id; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div id="scarica<?php echo $id; ?>" class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" onclick="window.location.href='magazzino.php'" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Scarica</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="codice">Codice:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="hidden" name="minus_stocks_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="descrizione" value="<?php echo $descrizione; ?>">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codice" name="codice" required readonly value="<?php echo $codice; ?>"> </div>
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="ubicazione">Ubicazione:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ubicazione" name="ubicazione" required readonly value="<?php echo $ubicazione; ?>"> </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="quantita">Quantità:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantita" name="quantita" autofocus required min="1"> </div>
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="causale">Causale:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <select required id="causale" name="causale">
                                <option value="">Seleziona</option>
                                <option value="Scarico">Scarico</option>
                                <option value="Scarto">Scarto</option>
                                <option value="Spedito">Spedito</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="minus_company"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> Scarica</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="window.location.href='magazzino.php'" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> Annulla</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The page contains other 3 div id: this is for unload then there are load, edit & delete

This is what i expect to have
[image]

This is what i have with this code

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'>                                  
<a href="crudMagazzino.php#scarica?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&amp;
                                      codice=<?php echo $codice; ?>&amp;
                                      cod_forn=<?php echo $cod_forn; ?>&amp;
                                      ubicazione=<?php echo $ubicazione; ?>&amp;
                                      descrizione=<?php echo $descrizione; ?>&amp;
                                      package=<?php echo $package; ?>&amp;
                                      quantita=<?php echo $quantita; ?>&amp;">                                 
<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' href="#scarica=<?php echo $id;?>" data-toggle="modal"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus' aria-hidden='true' title="Scarica"></span></button>
</a>
```

removing #scarica from href="crudMagazzino.php#scarica?id=

[image]

opens all the modal togheter with the corrrect data (strings value). I need to use the anchor # to open the desired modal

Answer (score 0):

You could just use POST and set the params in a hidden input inside the form and grab the values on the scaricaMagazzino.php page but if you must go the GET route then try using form action "get" and assign values in hidden inputs

If you wish to use POST method instead the below code will work

```
<?php

<!-- value of the PHP goes here

$id = 5;
$codice = 5; etc -->

?>

<html>
    <form action="scaricaMagazzino.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="codice" value="<?php echo $codice;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="cod_forn" value="<?php echo $cod_forn;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="ubicazione" value="<?php echo $ubicazione;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="descrizione" value="<?php echo $descrizione;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="package" value="<?php echo $package;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantita" value="<?php echo $quantita;?>">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal">Submit</button>
    </form>
</html>
```

then retrieve the values from scaricaMagazzino.php like so

```
<?php //include 'menu.html'; 
$id = $_POST['id'];
$codice = $_POST['codice'];
$cod_forn = $_POST['cod_forn'];
$ubicazione = $_POST['ubicazione'];
$descrizione = $_POST['descrizione'];
$package = $_POST['package'];
$quantita = $_POST['quantita'];
?>
```

Comment: Would you prefer to use post instead of get?

Comment: Yes I can try this way

Comment: Do you mean to change $id = $_GET['id']; in $id = $_POST['id']; etc? I tryied and don't work too

Comment: check the edit, I added how you can achieve this with post

Comment: In this way have the same situation as my edit post (second image removing #scarica from href="crudMagazzino.php#scarica?id= ). The strings are passed to the crudMagazzino.php page but the selected modal don't open